# Access a button using its string name and change its back color

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to access buttons using their string names and change their `BackColor` property.

I tried using `this.control[string key]` and `this.controls.Find(string, bool)`, but none of these work.

```cs
 oleDbConnection.Open();
 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE FLIGHTNO = '" + variables.depFlightNo + "'", oleDbConnection);

 OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 while (reader.Read())
 {
     string seat = reader[3].ToString();
     this.Controls[seat].BackColor = Color.Red;
 }
 reader.Close();
```

Comment: In which way _it didn't work_ ? Do you have an exception or the color is not changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oleDbConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE FLIGHTNO = '" + variables.depFlightNo + "'", oleDbConnection);

OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
    {
        string seat = reader[3].ToString();
        foreach (Button s in this.Controls) 
//if the controls are in different place
//like panel or groupbox change "this.Controls" to "groupBox.Controls"
        {
           if (s.Name == seat)
           {
              s.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
           }
        }

    }
    reader.Close();
```

Comment: I suppose that when the Poster says _names_ it refers to the button control name not to its caption text

Comment: the button does not have a text ... i want to access it using its name not its text.

Comment: @user3706307 I edited my post. Please check whether your query returns some value or not.

Comment: i guess loop is not working .. its only accessing one button and the loop stops.

Comment: @user3706307 How many buttons do you have in your Windows Form? Are they in some panel, groupbox or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

If the button controls are contained in different contaier instead of the the form, your code cannot find them.

Instead of `this` you need to use the button control container. (a group box? a panel?)

So, for example, if your buttons are inside a Panel called `panel1` your loop should be changed to

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string seat = reader[3].ToString();
    Controls[] found = this.panel1.Controls.Find(seat, false);
    if(found != null && found.Length > 0)
      found[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

(Added a bit of checking on the control name, to avoid an exception if the control is not found)